# Long Count Mayan Date in Python

Tags: python

I need to compile a program that can convert a Gregorian date to a Mayan one. I also need to use 01/01/1970 as a reference date.

The following auxiliary functions work accordingly and have no mistakes.

```
# turns dates into tuples


def dmj(date):

"""
>>> dmj('01/01/1970')
(1, 1, 1970)
>>> dmj('00012+00012+02012')
(12, 12, 2012)
"""

tup = ()
for i in date:
    if i.isdigit() == False and i != ' ':
        date = date.replace(i, ' ')

number_str = ''
for i in date:
    number_str += i
    if i == ' ':
        number = int(number_str)
        tup += (number,)
        number_str = ''
tup += (int(number_str),)
return tup

# counts days that have passed since 01/01/1970

def daysPassed(date):
"""
>>> daysPassed('01/01/1970')
0
>>> daysPassed('20-7-1988')
6775
>>> daysPassed('00012+00012+02012')
15686
"""

from datetime import date
tup = dmj(date)
begin = date(1970, 1, 1)
end = date(tup[2], tup[1], tup[0])
passed = abs(end - begin)        
return passed.days
```

My idea was to first calculate how many days have passed since the beginning of this pictun (20 baktuns long) in 01/01/1970 and then added the days passed since then according to the given date.

In the Mayan calendar a day is refered to as a kin. Their periods (within one pictun) are as follows:

20 kin = 1 uinal; 18 uinal = 1 tun; 20 tun = 1 katun; 20 katun = 1 baktun

In the long count notation the Mayan date for 01/01/1970 is '12.17.16.7.5'. Baktun are written first, then katuns, etc... Mayan dates start from 0. Basically the first kin of a uinal is number zero and the last one number 19, twenty in total.

I've first compiled the following:

```
def mayanDate(date, separation='')

"""
>>> mayanDate('01/01/1970')
'12/17/16/7/5'
>>> mayaDate('20-7-1988', separator='/')
'12/18/15/4/0'
>>> mayaDate('00012+00012+02012', separator='-')
'12-19-19-17-11'
>>> mayaDate('21 12 2012', separator='+')
'13+0+0+0+0'
>>> mayaDate('26.03.2407')
'14.0.0.0.0'
"""
days = daysPassed(date) + 13 * 144000 + 18 * 7200\
 + 17 * 400 + 8 * 20 + 6     
baktun = str((days //((20 **3) * 18)) - 1)
days = days % ((20 **3) * 18)    
katun = str((days //((20 **2) * 18)) - 1)
days = days % ((20 **2) * 18)    
tun = str((days // (20 **2)) - 1)
days = days % (20 **2)    
uinal = str((days // 20) - 1)
days = days % 20 - 1

kin = str(days)
mayanlist = [baktun, katun, tun, uinal, kin]

for i in date:
    if i.isdigit() == False and separator == '':
        separator = i
        break

mayandate = separator.join(mayanlist)
return mayandate
```

For some strange reason only 01/01/1970 returns the correct Mayan long notation, despite counting from the beginning of an entire pictun (7,900 years in length!). For all other dates it seems to advance too fast through the calendar, despite my second auxiliary function returning the correct values (even for millennia into the future).

I wonder where's the mistake. For instance `mayanDate('20-7-1988')` returns `'12-18-15-6-0'` instead of `'12-18-15-4-0'` and `mayanDate('21 12 2012')` returns `'13 0 1 12 0'` instead of `'13 0 0 0 0'`.

Comment: Have you observed this in a debugger yet?

Comment: I have. Yet, little avail as this function doesn't have to calculate that much. All I see is incorrect values appearing for kin, uinals, etc... and the further I advance from January 1st, 1970 the more removed it is in the future. What I don't seem to get how it's possible that 01/01/1970 is calculated correctly despite my beginning the count from millennia in the past.

Comment: Interesting to note. Also baktun are culculate wrong in mayanDate('12-12-2012'). It returns '13-0-1-11-11' instead of '12-19-19-17-11' Very curious indeed. Perhaps I shouldn't start with baktun but with kin?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're seeing with the negative 1 kin for date '15/01/1970' is due to the removal of one from every date ordinal during the calculation. Taking `x%20` will always return a value between 0 and 19 inclusive. Taking one from the result necessarily shifts this range to -1 to 18 inclusive.

The number added to the result of daysPassed(date) seems to be a conversion of the long form of 1/1/1970, with one added to each digit. I'm assuming this has been done to counter the fact that the Mayan calendar starts counting at zero, but is unnecessary. The Mayan date 0.0.0.0.1.5 counts 25, not 151646. This doesn't appear to be the source of the error though, since removing this issue from my own code, I still get the same results as described for the 20-7-1988 and 21-12-2012.

I finally rooted out the error when I went back and switched out all the magic numbers in my code for named constants (it makes the code far easier to debug, read and maintain). You state there are 18 uinal in a tun, and 20 tun in a katun, but these numbers are reversed in the code.

Here's my code:

```
def mayanDate(date_str, seperation=','):
days_in_kin     = 1
kin_in_uinal    = 20
uinal_in_tun    = 18
tun_in_katun    = 20
katun_in_baktun = 20

days_in_uinal   = days_in_kin * kin_in_uinal
days_in_tun     = days_in_uinal * uinal_in_tun
days_in_katun   = days_in_tun * tun_in_katun
days_in_baktun  = days_in_katun * katun_in_baktun

days_1970 = 12 * days_in_baktun \
    + 17 * days_in_katun\
    + 16 * days_in_tun\
    + 7 * days_in_uinal\
    + 5 * days_in_kin

total_days = daysPassed(date_str) + days_1970

baktun = total_days // days_in_baktun
total_days -= baktun * days_in_baktun
katun = total_days // days_in_katun
total_days -= katun * days_in_katun
tun = total_days // days_in_tun
total_days -= tun * days_in_tun
uinal = total_days // days_in_uinal
total_days -= uinal * days_in_uinal
kin = total_days // days_in_kin

print seperation.join(map(str, (baktun, katun, tun, uinal, kin)))
```

(I subtracted the previous calculations from total days, rather than using a modulo operator, since I feel it's cleaner. I guess it's a matter of personal preference.)

Answer (score 0):

I may have found something.

```
>>>mayanDate('15/01/1970')
'12/17/16/8/-1'
```

Obviously not possible. -1 has to be 19 here and 8 has to be 7. It seems to turn month too early. Still not out why 01/01/1970 remains correct here. No idea what's so special about that date.